# Jquery append html, not variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to append the vidyourl3, but my script keeps adding vidyourl3 name only. Where am I doing a mistake ?

```
var vidyourl3 = '<iframe id="vide3" width="255" height="195" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Nficz8WZwrk?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>';

kacki = 3;

$("#vidgelcekburaya").html("vidyourl"+kacki);
```

Comment: you can't create variable name like that

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Variable" Variables in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple urls then create an object to hold those references as given below

```
var urls = {
    vidyourl3: '<iframe id="vide3" width="255" height="195" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Nficz8WZwrk?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>'
}
```

then use the object key along with bracket notation to access the value

```
kacki = 3;
$("#vidgelcekburaya").html(urls["vidyourl"+kacki]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're putting a literal string in your html.  Take the quotes off of your vidyourl and it will work:

```
$("#vidgelcekburaya").html(vidyourl3 + kacki);
```

Another problem which is hard to decide what you're trying to do is; your first variable is called vidyourl3, while you then put in vidyourl in your html replace.  Which one should it be?

Comment: sorry again I think what the OP is trying to do is to create the variable name dynamically like `"vidyourl"+kacki` to access the content of the variable named `vidyourl3`... you are not doing the same

Comment: Sure, but he's not doing the same by naming his FIRST variable vidyourl3.  What he would be writing is vidyourl33 There's no variable called vidyourl.  He can make `vidyourl` as a first variable, then number all the variables he wants, then use `kacki` to number them, either way, when you put quotes around a variables, it turns into a string.

Comment: @ntgCleaner No. Notice he left off the `3` in the literal string => `"vidyourl"`...

Comment: I see, it wasn't apparent that it was on purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.vidyourl3 = '<iframe id="vide3" width="255" height="195" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Nficz8WZwrk?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>';

kacki = 3;

$("#vidgelcekburaya").html(window["vidyourl"+kacki]);
```

If your variable *needs* to be in the local scope, try

```
var vidyourl3 = '<iframe id="vide3" width="255" height="195" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Nficz8WZwrk?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>';

kacki = 3;

$("#vidgelcekburaya").html(eval("vidyourl"+kacki));
```

I wouldn't use this method, because `eval` can be *kind of* scary.

Comment: if the object is the global scope, if it is in the local scope it won't work

Comment: Sorry, why does this work? am I misunderstanding something? all the upvotes?  It still prints a literal.

Comment: @ntgCleaner it will work if the variable `vidyourl3` is in the global scope... all global scoped variables are properties of the window object

Comment: @ArunPJohny Edited, sorry

Comment: I understand by making it global, but when you put quotes around a variable, it's not a variable anymore; it's a string.  Is this not the case?

Comment: @ntgCleaner No, because you're finding the variable in the `Window` object

Comment: @ntgCleaner you should have a look at member operator - bracket notation

Comment: @ntgCleaner `window.vidyourl3 === window["vidyourl3"]` Just different notations...